# CUDA not waiting for kernel to finish

Tags: cuda

So i have a illegal memory access was encountered error when i try to launch some kernels in a loop like this:

```
for (int bitId = 0; bitId < sizeof(uint32_t) * 8; bitId++)
    {
        // Extract bits
        extractBits <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (d_in, n, d_bits, bitId);

        // Compute nOnesBefore       
        scanKernel <<< gridSize, blockSize, smem >>> (d_bits, n, d_nOnesBefore, d_bSums);

        int zero = 0;
        CHECK(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(bCount, &zero, sizeof(int)));
        CHECK(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(bDoneCount, &zero, sizeof(int)));

        // Compute rank
        computeRank <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (d_in, n, d_out, d_bits, d_nOnesBefore);

        // Swap d_in and d_out
        uint32_t* temp = d_in;
        d_in = d_out;
        d_out = temp;
    }
```

And i debug and found out this ‘extractBits’ function was calculate wrong. When I try to print to see problem, the error rarely happen. So i realize the more delay i add, the less chance error happen. I add something like this and it run fine without error:

```
for (int bitId = 0; bitId < sizeof(uint32_t) * 8; bitId++)
    {
        // Extract bits
        extractBits <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (d_in, n, d_bits, bitId);

        // Dummy copy to delay, do nothing.
        CHECK(cudaMemcpy(src, d_in, sizeof(uint32_t) * n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

        // Compute nOnesBefore       
        scanKernel <<< gridSize, blockSize, smem >>> (d_bits, n, d_nOnesBefore, d_bSums);

        int zero = 0;
        CHECK(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(bCount, &zero, sizeof(int)));
        CHECK(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(bDoneCount, &zero, sizeof(int)));

        // Compute rank
        computeRank <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (d_in, n, d_out, d_bits, d_nOnesBefore);

        // Swap d_in and d_out
        uint32_t* temp = d_in;
        d_in = d_out;
        d_out = temp;
    }
```

Here is source code(it only can run with gpu like T4 on colab, P100 can't):

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHECK(call)\
{\
    const cudaError_t error = call;\
    if (error != cudaSuccess)\
    {\
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s:%d, ", __FILE__, __LINE__);\
        fprintf(stderr, "code: %d, reason: %s\n", error,\
                cudaGetErrorString(error));\
        exit(1);\
    }\
}

struct GpuTimer
{
    cudaEvent_t start;
    cudaEvent_t stop;

    GpuTimer()
    {
        cudaEventCreate(&start);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    }

    ~GpuTimer()
    {
        cudaEventDestroy(start);
        cudaEventDestroy(stop);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
        cudaEventSynchronize(start);
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    }

    float Elapsed()
    {
        float elapsed;
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, start, stop);
        return elapsed;
    }
};

// Sequential Radix Sort
// "const uint32_t * in" means: the memory region pointed by "in" is read-only
void sortByHost(const uint32_t * in, int n,
                uint32_t * out)
{
    int * bits = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int * nOnesBefore = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    uint32_t * src = (uint32_t *)malloc(n * sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t * originalSrc = src; // To free memory later
    memcpy(src, in, n * sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t * dst = out;

    // Loop from LSB (Least Significant Bit) to MSB (Most Significant Bit)
    // In each loop, sort elements according to the current bit from src to dst 
    // (using STABLE counting sort)
    for (int bitIdx = 0; bitIdx < sizeof(uint32_t) * 8; bitIdx++)
    {
        // Extract bits
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            bits[i] = (src[i] >> bitIdx) & 1;

        // Compute nOnesBefore
        nOnesBefore[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            nOnesBefore[i] = nOnesBefore[i-1] + bits[i-1];

        // Compute rank and write to dst
        int nZeros = n - nOnesBefore[n-1] - bits[n-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int rank;
            if (bits[i] == 0)
                rank = i - nOnesBefore[i];
            else
                rank = nZeros + nOnesBefore[i];
            dst[rank] = src[i];
        }

        // Swap src and dst
        uint32_t * temp = src;
        src = dst;
        dst = temp;
    }

    // Does out array contain results?
    memcpy(out, src, n * sizeof(uint32_t));

    // Free memory
    free(originalSrc);
    free(bits);
    free(nOnesBefore);
}

__global__ void extractBits(uint32_t* in, int n, int* out, int bitId)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < n)
        out[i] = (in[i] >> bitId) & 1;
}

__device__ int bCount = 0;
volatile __device__ int bDoneCount = 0;

__global__ void scanKernel(int* in, int n, int* out, volatile int* bSums)
{
    __shared__ int blockId;
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        blockId = atomicAdd(&bCount, 1);
    }
    __syncthreads();

    // 1. Each block loads data from GMEM to SMEM
    extern __shared__ int s_data[];

    int i = blockId * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < n)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            s_data[threadIdx.x] = 0;
        else
            s_data[threadIdx.x] = in[i - 1];
        __syncthreads();

        // 2. Each block does scan with data on SMEM
        for (int stride = 1; stride < blockDim.x; stride *= 2)
        {
            int neededVal;
            if (threadIdx.x >= stride)
                neededVal = s_data[threadIdx.x - stride];
            __syncthreads();
            if (threadIdx.x >= stride)
                s_data[threadIdx.x] += neededVal;
            __syncthreads();
        }

        // 3. Each block write results from SMEM to GMEM
        out[i] = s_data[threadIdx.x];

        if (bSums != NULL)
        {
            if (threadIdx.x == 0)
            {
                bSums[blockId] = s_data[blockDim.x - 1];

                if (blockId > 0)
                {
                    while (bDoneCount < blockId) {}
                    bSums[blockId] += bSums[blockId - 1];
                    __threadfence();
                }
                bDoneCount += 1;
            }
            __syncthreads();

            if (i + blockDim.x < n)
                out[i + blockDim.x] += bSums[blockId];
        }
    }
}

__global__ void computeRank(uint32_t* in, int n, uint32_t* out, int* bits, int* nOnesBefore)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int nZeros = n - nOnesBefore[n - 1] - bits[n - 1];

    if (i < n)
    {
        int rank;
        if (bits[i] == 0)
            rank = i - nOnesBefore[i];
        else
            rank = nZeros + nOnesBefore[i];
        out[rank] = in[i];
    }
}

// Parallel Radix Sort
void sortByDevice(const uint32_t * in, int n, uint32_t * out, int blockSize)
{
    uint32_t* src = (uint32_t*)malloc(n * sizeof(uint32_t));
    // TODO
    int *d_bits, *d_nOnesBefore;
    size_t nBytes = n * sizeof(int);
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_bits, nBytes));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_nOnesBefore, nBytes));

    uint32_t * d_in, * d_out;
    nBytes = n * sizeof(uint32_t);
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_in, nBytes));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_out, nBytes));

    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_in, in, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    int gridSize = (n - 1) / blockSize + 1;

    int* d_bSums;
    if (gridSize > 1)
    {
        CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_bSums, gridSize * sizeof(int)));
    }
    else
    {
        d_bSums = NULL;
    }
    size_t smem = blockSize * sizeof(int);

    // Loop from LSB (Least Significant Bit) to MSB (Most Significant Bit)
    // In each loop, sort elements according to the current bit from src to dst 
    // (using STABLE counting sort)
    for (int bitId = 0; bitId < sizeof(uint32_t) * 8; bitId++)
    {
        // Extract bits
        extractBits <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (d_in, n, d_bits, bitId);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        CHECK(cudaGetLastError());

        CHECK(cudaMemcpy(src, d_in, sizeof(uint32_t) * n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

        // Compute nOnesBefore       
        scanKernel <<< gridSize, blockSize, smem >>> (d_bits, n, d_nOnesBefore, d_bSums);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        CHECK(cudaGetLastError());

        int zero = 0;
        CHECK(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(bCount, &zero, sizeof(int)));
        CHECK(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(bDoneCount, &zero, sizeof(int)));

        // Compute rank and write to d_out
        computeRank <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (d_in, n, d_out, d_bits, d_nOnesBefore);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        CHECK(cudaGetLastError());
        
        // Swap d_in and d_out
        uint32_t* temp = d_in;
        d_in = d_out;
        d_out = temp;
    }

    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(out, d_in, nBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    

    // Free memory  
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_bits));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_nOnesBefore));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_in));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_out));

    if (gridSize > 1)
        CHECK(cudaFree(d_bSums));

    free(src);
}

// Radix Sort
void sort(const uint32_t * in, int n, 
        uint32_t * out, 
        bool useDevice=false, int blockSize=1)
{
    GpuTimer timer; 
    timer.Start();

    if (useDevice == false)
    {
        printf("\nRadix Sort by host\n");
        sortByHost(in, n, out);
    }
    else // use device
    {
        printf("\nRadix Sort by device\n");
        sortByDevice(in, n, out, blockSize);
    }

    timer.Stop();
    printf("Time: %.3f ms\n", timer.Elapsed());
}

void printDeviceInfo()
{
    cudaDeviceProp devProv;
    CHECK(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&devProv, 0));
    printf("**********GPU info**********\n");
    printf("Name: %s\n", devProv.name);
    printf("Compute capability: %d.%d\n", devProv.major, devProv.minor);
    printf("Num SMs: %d\n", devProv.multiProcessorCount);
    printf("Max num threads per SM: %d\n", devProv.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor); 
    printf("Max num warps per SM: %d\n", devProv.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor / devProv.warpSize);
    printf("GMEM: %zu byte\n", devProv.totalGlobalMem);
    printf("SMEM per SM: %zu byte\n", devProv.sharedMemPerMultiprocessor);
    printf("SMEM per block: %zu byte\n", devProv.sharedMemPerBlock);
    printf("****************************\n");
}

void checkCorrectness(uint32_t * out, uint32_t * correctOut, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (out[i] != correctOut[i])
        {
            printf("INCORRECT :(\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("CORRECT :)\n");
}

void printArray(uint32_t * a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%i ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // PRINT OUT DEVICE INFO
    printDeviceInfo();

    // SET UP INPUT SIZE
    //int n = 50; // For test by eye
    int n = (1 << 24) + 1;
    printf("\nInput size: %d\n", n);

    // ALLOCATE MEMORIES
    size_t bytes = n * sizeof(uint32_t);
    uint32_t * in = (uint32_t *)malloc(bytes);
    uint32_t * out = (uint32_t *)malloc(bytes); // Device result
    uint32_t * correctOut = (uint32_t *)malloc(bytes); // Host result

    // SET UP INPUT DATA
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //in[i] = rand() % 255; // For test by eye
        in[i] = rand();
    }
    //printArray(in, n); // For test by eye

    // DETERMINE BLOCK SIZE
    int blockSize = 256; // Default 
    if (argc == 2)
        blockSize = atoi(argv[1]);

    // SORT BY HOST
    sort(in, n, correctOut);
    //printArray(correctOut, n); // For test by eye
    
    // SORT BY DEVICE
    sort(in, n, out, true, blockSize);
    //printArray(out, n); // For test by eye
    checkCorrectness(out, correctOut, n);

    // FREE MEMORIES
    free(in);
    free(out);
    free(correctOut);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So what's wrong with my code, can someone explain it for me?

Comment: That is how It works. Kernel launches are asynchronous and GPUs can run multiple kernels  simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably multiple issues with this code.  I will list 3 and then give some additional commentary.

1. You have illegal use of `__syncthreads()`:

   ```
    if (i < n)   <--------------------------------------
    {                                                   |
        if (i == 0)                                     |
            s_data[threadIdx.x] = 0;                    |
        else                                            |
            s_data[threadIdx.x] = in[i - 1];            |
        __syncthreads();  <-----------------------------
   ```

   see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions).  I don't think this is a central issue, however.
2. I'm reasonably confident, for correctness, you need a `__threadfence()` here:

   ```
        if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        {
            bSums[blockId] = s_data[blockDim.x - 1];
            __threadfence();  // added
            if (blockId > 0)
   ```

   to handle the interaction between block 0 and block 1.
3. The central issue, according to my testing is that you have a global memory race condition that you have not properly accounted for.  Let's consider this section of code:

   ```
            // 3. Each block write results from SMEM to GMEM
            out[i] = s_data[threadIdx.x];  // line A

            if (bSums != NULL)
            {
                if (threadIdx.x == 0)
                {
                    bSums[blockId] = s_data[blockDim.x - 1];

                    if (blockId > 0)
                    {
                        while (bDoneCount < blockId) {}
                        bSums[blockId] += bSums[blockId - 1];
                        __threadfence();
                    }
                    bDoneCount += 1;
                }
                __syncthreads();

                if (i + blockDim.x < n)
                    out[i + blockDim.x] += bSums[blockId];  // line B
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   where I have marked line A and line B.   For correctness, this requires for any given block X, that the block X+1 must have executed line A before block X executes line B. I don't see anything that enforces that.

I've made the following test code primarily to test the assertion in item 3 above.  The key addition is to require any block to not proceed to line B until the next higher numbered block has passed line A.  Since you already have a `bDoneCount` counter that is available for this purpose, I reuse that for this kind of crude inter-block synchronization.  A few caveats:

- I don't recommend this programming approach at all.
- I'm not suggesting anything I'm demonstrating here is correct.  It's mostly your code, and my goal here is to lend credence to the assertion in item 3 above.
- Yes, this additional block-to-block synchronization that I added causes your overall code to run **much** more slowly.  As far as I am concerned, I don't care about that, because none of the work here is a sensible approach to writing a high-performance radix sort.
- If you care about high performance, you should not be writing your own scan kernel, at least not the one you have here
- If you care about high performance, you should be using a library implementation, either a library implementation of sort, or at least a library implementation of prefix sum.  The prefix sum here is not a high performance realization.

With those caveats out of the way, here is a test code modification of your code, addressing some of the 3 items I listed.  It still does not address the improper use of syncthreads.  However that is a fairly mechanical fix, once you understand the underlying issue and requirements.  The following code passed all the testing I cared to throw at it.  You'll find additional modifications beyond what I described, mainly to facilitate my testing and problem visibility:

```
$ cat t109.cu
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHECK(call)\
{\
    const cudaError_t error = call;\
    if (error != cudaSuccess)\
    {\
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s:%d, ", __FILE__, __LINE__);\
        fprintf(stderr, "code: %d, reason: %s\n", error,\
                cudaGetErrorString(error));\
        exit(1);\
    }\
}

struct GpuTimer
{
    cudaEvent_t start;
    cudaEvent_t stop;

    GpuTimer()
    {
        cudaEventCreate(&start);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    }

    ~GpuTimer()
    {
        cudaEventDestroy(start);
        cudaEventDestroy(stop);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
        cudaEventSynchronize(start);
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    }

    float Elapsed()
    {
        float elapsed;
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, start, stop);
        return elapsed;
    }
};

// Sequential Radix Sort
// "const uint32_t * in" means: the memory region pointed by "in" is read-only
void sortByHost(const uint32_t * in, int n,
                uint32_t * out)
{
    int * bits = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int * nOnesBefore = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    uint32_t * src = (uint32_t *)malloc(n * sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t * originalSrc = src; // To free memory later
    memcpy(src, in, n * sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t * dst = out;

    // Loop from LSB (Least Significant Bit) to MSB (Most Significant Bit)
    // In each loop, sort elements according to the current bit from src to dst
    // (using STABLE counting sort)
    for (int bitIdx = 0; bitIdx < sizeof(uint32_t) * 8; bitIdx++)
    {
        // Extract bits
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            bits[i] = (src[i] >> bitIdx) & 1;

        // Compute nOnesBefore
        nOnesBefore[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            nOnesBefore[i] = nOnesBefore[i-1] + bits[i-1];

        // Compute rank and write to dst
        int nZeros = n - nOnesBefore[n-1] - bits[n-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int rank;
            if (bits[i] == 0)
                rank = i - nOnesBefore[i];
            else
                rank = nZeros + nOnesBefore[i];
            dst[rank] = src[i];
        }

        // Swap src and dst
        uint32_t * temp = src;
        src = dst;
        dst = temp;
    }

    // Does out array contain results?
    memcpy(out, src, n * sizeof(uint32_t));

    // Free memory
    free(originalSrc);
    free(bits);
    free(nOnesBefore);
}

__global__ void extractBits(uint32_t* in, int n, int* out, int bitId)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < n)
        out[i] = (in[i] >> bitId) & 1;
}

__device__ int bCount = 0;
volatile __device__ int bDoneCount = 0;

__global__ void scanKernel(int* in, int n, int* out, volatile int* bSums)
{
    __shared__ int blockId;
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        blockId = atomicAdd(&bCount, 1);
    }
    __syncthreads();

    // 1. Each block loads data from GMEM to SMEM
    extern __shared__ int s_data[];

    int i = blockId * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < n)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            s_data[threadIdx.x] = 0;
        else
            s_data[threadIdx.x] = in[i - 1];
        __syncthreads();

        // 2. Each block does scan with data on SMEM
        for (int stride = 1; stride < blockDim.x; stride *= 2)
        {
            int neededVal;
            if (threadIdx.x >= stride)
                neededVal = s_data[threadIdx.x - stride];
            __syncthreads();
            if (threadIdx.x >= stride)
                s_data[threadIdx.x] += neededVal;
            __syncthreads();
        }

        // 3. Each block write results from SMEM to GMEM
        out[i] = s_data[threadIdx.x];

        if (bSums != NULL)
        {
            if (threadIdx.x == 0)
            {
                bSums[blockId] = s_data[blockDim.x - 1];
                __threadfence();

                if (blockId > 0)
                {
                    while (bDoneCount < blockId) {}
                    bSums[blockId] += bSums[blockId - 1];
                    __threadfence();
                }
                bDoneCount += 1;
            }
            if (blockId < (gridDim.x-1)) {while (bDoneCount < (blockId+2)){};} // ADDED SYNC
            __syncthreads();

            if (i + blockDim.x < n)
                out[i + blockDim.x] += bSums[blockId];
        }
    }
}
__global__ void computeRank(uint32_t* in, int n, uint32_t* out, int* bits, int* nOnesBefore)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int nZeros = n - nOnesBefore[n - 1] - bits[n - 1];

    if (i < n)
    {
        int rank;
        if (bits[i] == 0)
            rank = i - nOnesBefore[i];
        else
            rank = nZeros + nOnesBefore[i];
        out[rank] = in[i];
    }
}

// Parallel Radix Sort
void sortByDevice(const uint32_t * in, int n, uint32_t * out, int blockSize)
{
    uint32_t* src = (uint32_t*)malloc(n * sizeof(uint32_t));
    // TODO
    int *d_bits, *d_nOnesBefore;
    size_t nBytes = n * sizeof(int);
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_bits, nBytes));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_nOnesBefore, nBytes));

    uint32_t * d_in, * d_out;
    nBytes = n * sizeof(uint32_t);
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_in, nBytes));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_out, nBytes));

    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_in, in, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

//    int gridSize = (n - 1) / blockSize + 1;
    int gridSize = (n+blockSize-1)/blockSize;
    int* d_bSums;
    if (gridSize > 1)
    {
        CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_bSums, gridSize * sizeof(int)));
    }
    else
    {
        d_bSums = NULL;
    }
    size_t smem = blockSize * sizeof(int);

    // Loop from LSB (Least Significant Bit) to MSB (Most Significant Bit)
    // In each loop, sort elements according to the current bit from src to dst
    // (using STABLE counting sort)
    for (int bitId = 0; bitId < sizeof(uint32_t) * 8; bitId++)
    {
        // Extract bits
        extractBits <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (d_in, n, d_bits, bitId);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        CHECK(cudaGetLastError());

    //    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(src, d_in, sizeof(uint32_t) * n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

        // Compute nOnesBefore
        scanKernel <<< gridSize, blockSize, smem >>> (d_bits, n, d_nOnesBefore, d_bSums);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        CHECK(cudaGetLastError());

        int zero = 0;
        CHECK(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(bCount, &zero, sizeof(int)));
        CHECK(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(bDoneCount, &zero, sizeof(int)));

        // Compute rank and write to d_out
        computeRank <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (d_in, n, d_out, d_bits, d_nOnesBefore);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        CHECK(cudaGetLastError());

        // Swap d_in and d_out
        uint32_t* temp = d_in;
        d_in = d_out;
        d_out = temp;
    }

    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(out, d_in, nBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));


    // Free memory
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_bits));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_nOnesBefore));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_in));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_out));

    if (gridSize > 1)
        CHECK(cudaFree(d_bSums));

    free(src);
}

// Radix Sort
void sort(const uint32_t * in, int n,
        uint32_t * out,
        bool useDevice=false, int blockSize=1)
{
    GpuTimer timer;
    timer.Start();

    if (useDevice == false)
    {
        printf("\nRadix Sort by host\n");
        sortByHost(in, n, out);
    }
    else // use device
    {
        printf("\nRadix Sort by device\n");
        sortByDevice(in, n, out, blockSize);
    }

    timer.Stop();
    printf("Time: %.3f ms\n", timer.Elapsed());
}

void printDeviceInfo()
{
    cudaDeviceProp devProv;
    CHECK(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&devProv, 0));
    printf("**********GPU info**********\n");
    printf("Name: %s\n", devProv.name);
    printf("Compute capability: %d.%d\n", devProv.major, devProv.minor);
    printf("Num SMs: %d\n", devProv.multiProcessorCount);
    printf("Max num threads per SM: %d\n", devProv.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor);
    printf("Max num warps per SM: %d\n", devProv.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor / devProv.warpSize);
    printf("GMEM: %zu byte\n", devProv.totalGlobalMem);
    printf("SMEM per SM: %zu byte\n", devProv.sharedMemPerMultiprocessor);
    printf("SMEM per block: %zu byte\n", devProv.sharedMemPerBlock);
    printf("****************************\n");
}

void checkCorrectness(uint32_t * out, uint32_t * correctOut, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (out[i] != correctOut[i])
        {
            printf("INCORRECT : index: %d, was: %u, should be: %u\n", i, out[i], correctOut[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("CORRECT :)\n");
}

void printArray(uint32_t * a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%i ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
bool is_sorted(uint32_t *data, int n){
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
          if (data[i-1] > data[i]) return false;
        return true;
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // PRINT OUT DEVICE INFO
    printDeviceInfo();

    // SET UP INPUT SIZE
    //int n = 50; // For test by eye
    int n = (1 << 24)+ 1;
    if (argc > 1)  n = (1 << atoi(argv[1]));
    printf("\nInput size: %d\n", n);

    // ALLOCATE MEMORIES
    size_t bytes = n * sizeof(uint32_t);
    uint32_t * in = (uint32_t *)malloc(bytes);
    uint32_t * out = (uint32_t *)malloc(bytes); // Device result
    uint32_t * correctOut = (uint32_t *)malloc(bytes); // Host result

    // SET UP INPUT DATA
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //in[i] = rand() % 255; // For test by eye
        in[i] = rand()%n;
    }
    //printArray(in, n); // For test by eye

    // DETERMINE BLOCK SIZE
    int blockSize = 256; // Default
#if 0
    if (argc == 2)
        blockSize = atoi(argv[1]);
#endif
    // SORT BY HOST
    sort(in, n, correctOut);
    //printArray(correctOut, n); // For test by eye
    if (!is_sorted(correctOut, n)) printf("host sorting error\n");
    // SORT BY DEVICE
    sort(in, n, out, true, blockSize);
    if (!is_sorted(out, n)) printf("device sorting error\n");
    //printArray(out, n); // For test by eye
    checkCorrectness(out, correctOut, n);

    // FREE MEMORIES
    free(in);
    free(out);
    free(correctOut);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
$ nvcc -o t109 t109.cu
$ ./t109
**********GPU info**********
Name: GeForce GTX 960
Compute capability: 5.2
Num SMs: 8
Max num threads per SM: 2048
Max num warps per SM: 64
GMEM: 2099052544 byte
SMEM per SM: 98304 byte
SMEM per block: 49152 byte
****************************

Input size: 16777217

Radix Sort by host
Time: 9495.082 ms

Radix Sort by device
Time: 11949.311 ms
CORRECT :)
$
```

(CUDA 11.1, Fedora 29, GTX960)

You may still have issues.  A few suggestions:

1. Make sure you are not running on a machine that has a kernel timeout.  I don't think any of these kernels should run for 2 seconds or longer, but see item 2 below.  You can tell if a kernel timeout is in effect using the `deviceQuery` sample code.
2. Make sure, if on windows, you are compiling a release project, not a debug project.  Compiling a debug project (or compiling with `-G` whether on windows or linux) will make your kernels run more slowly.

Comment: I understand first and third issues. But second one, i don't see any interaction between block 0 and block 1 at all.  
```
bSums[blockId] = s_data[blockDim.x - 1];
```  
This one is same block. Why we need block-to-block synchronization here?

Comment: Thread block 1 consumes the value written to global memory by threadblock 0 here: `bSums[blockId] += bSums[blockId - 1];`.  There is an ordering issue.  Threadblock 1 waits until threadblock 0 has updated `bDoneCount` before proceeding to that line.  However if we don't enforce ordering of the global memory writes, the write by threadblock 0 to `bDoneCount` may become visible to threadblock 1 *before* the write to `bSums`.